# How to make setState take effect immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is an input element in my code:

```
<input id="input" className="ml-2" type="number" name="Qty" min="1" max="999" value={qty} onChange={(e) => {changeQty(e)}}/>
```

And the onChange handler is:

```
    const changeQty = (e) => {
        setQty(e.target.value);
        console.log(qty);
    }
```

So I suppose that whatever I enter in the input field will be printed out in the console, but the fact is there is delay.

For example, the default value is 1, then I type 2, then 1 will be printed out. Then I type 3, then 2 will be printed out. The number printed out is the previous one I entered instead of the current one, as shown below:

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to remove the delay?

I read [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately), but still cannot solve it.

I tried the code below as the answer indicates,

```
useEffect(() => {
    setQty(document.getElementById("input").value)
}, [qty]);
```

but an error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'qty' before initialization` occurred.

Thanks!

Comment: Without the whole code it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Where are you calling setState? A console.log outside the setState context will print the old value.

Comment: This boils down to the classic: "React setState is async" you have to use a callback or an effect to wait until the new state is set before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say from the current question, but I'm going to assume that you're writing a function component and are using a `useState` hook. That is, somewhere above the `changeQty` you have something like:

```
const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
```

If that's the case, then the answer is directly in the assignment of qty above. `qty` is set when you call the `useState` hook and will not change for the duration of the execution.

`setQty` **does not update the value of qty**. It updates the internal state, which will trigger a re-render. That means the *next time* your render function is invoked, `qty` will have the value you used.

But for the rest of the execution of the function, `qty` will remain whatever value it was when `useState` was called.

If you need the new value of `qty` in the same iteration of your function, you can capture that as a new variable.

```
const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
let updatedQty = qty;

const changeQty = (e) => {
  updatedQty = e.target.value;
  setQty(updatedQty);
  console.log(updatedQty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState()` has two forms that could help you here:

**Functional Form**

```js
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({}))
```

**Callback Form**

```js
this.setState(nextState, () => {
    // instructions for immediately-after the state update
})
```

It sounds like you could use the callback form here to defer some calculations into the callback.

Also, you can chain those if it's a warzone out there:

```js
this.setState(nextState, () => {
    this.setState(nextState, () => {
        this.setState(nextState, () => {
            // you can do this, but probably don't
        })
    })
})
```

But, notice the extreme indenting that is occurring; it's reminiscent of callback hell and Promise christmas-tree hell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that setQty is asynchronous.
Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(qty);
```

}, [qty]);

You will normally get current value in this console.log.
In your code, your console.log may execute before the state is updated because `setQty` not synchronous as you may think

Comment: Thank you, your answer also works for my question, but I am not only printing it out on console, I need the updated value to toggle the Add to cart button, but when I do document.getElementById("AddToCart").classList.add("disabled"); in the useEffect function, the element cannot be found. Thus, I have to accept another question which is simpler and more universal. Thanks you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share all of your code, it's difficult to answer your question exactly, but it looks like you're using React's hooks, so I've created an example that uses hooks correctly to set the `qty` state and log the current `qty` value.

```js
const Quantity = function() {
  const [qty, setQty] = React.useState(0);
  const changeQty = (e) => {
    setQty(e.target.value);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(qty);
  }, [qty]);
  
  return (
      <input id="input" className="ml-2" type="number" name="Qty" min="1" max="999" value={qty} onChange={(e) => {changeQty(e)}}/>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<Quantity />, document.getElementById("app_root"));
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.25/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app_root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer also works for my question, but I am not only printing it out on console, I need the updated value to toggle the `Add to cart` button, but when I do `document.getElementById("AddToCart").classList.add("disabled");` in the `useEffect` function, the element cannot be found. Thus, I have to accept another question which is simpler and more universal. Thanks you all the same!

Comment: @powerseed I'm glad you found an answer that worked for you. I think you should consider using some shared state between your `Quantity` component and your `AddToCart` component. In React code, using `document.getElementById` is an indication that you're circumventing the advantages that React provides.